# How to enable SQLite extended Result Codes through PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite

Statements like the one below gives the generic error code which is of not much help to diagnose the actual problem. To get more specific error code *SQLite extended Result Codes* needs to be enabled.

> echo "Eror Code: ".$db->lastErrorCode();

There is an SQLite routine to do so:

[SQLite C Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/extended_result_codes.html)

But finding no resource to do the same in **PHP** let me ask this question here. With thanks in advance.

Comment: The sqlite bindings of many languages don't provide a lot of the features of the C API. So you might be out of luck with PHP.

Comment: yeah, one has to sorrily agree with this reality!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the method to get the last error message in conjunction with the one you already use to get the last error code:

```
echo "Eror Code: ".$db->lastErrorCode(); 
echo "Error Message: ".$db->lastErrorMsg();
```

Comment: I tried the both, but what I actually want is the error code only.

Comment: For example:- Error Code : 19 - Foreign key constraint failed. Error Code : 19 -Columns col1,col2 are not unique. The error code is generic,i.e, you get the same code for two different errors. However, I want the more specific codes.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your needs... I though you want more detail because you where getting only an error code and not a message.

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php) you can use `$db->setAttribute(PDO::SQLITE_ATTR_EXTENDED_RESULT_CODES, true);` or `new PDO('sqlite::memory:', '', '', [PDO::SQLITE_ATTR_EXTENDED_RESULT_CODES => TRUE]);`.

The extended error code available via `$db->lastExtendedErrorCode()`.